# What should I do if rpm -e never completes?

Tags: rpm

In a Fedora 19 box I am trying to erase the AdobeReader_enu package.

```
sudo rpm -e AdobeReader_enu
```

never completes, it runs the same pattern of hard drive crunching over and over. Is there any way to unconditionally force erase that package and repair whatever rpm did wrong?

Comment: You do not make Linux any better by digging out my old posts and downvoting them to retalliate for my criticism of direction Linux is going in. You only make Linux crowd look hostile and obnoxious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run it through `strace` in order to check what it is doing:

```
strace -o rpm.strace -ft rpm -e AdobeReader_enu
```

You can try to get a useful error message with

```
rpm -e --test AdobeReader_enu
```

Deleting the files should not be the problem so you could stick to removing them and ignore scripts and triggers:

```
rpm -e --noscripts --notriggers AdobeReader_enu
```

Comment: I did not have time to investigate into it and ended up forcing the install of the correct version by issuing `rpm -Uvh --force`. The correct version installed without issues. I like your answer, just do not have the resources to follow through with this.